# Use async/await on synchronous operations (mainly to stay on UI thread)

Tags: c#, task, async-await

I'm trying to run some stuff asynchronous. Here's my code:

```
    private async void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         await Search();
    }

    // Inside search there is no async operation
    public Task Search()
    {
        // search for data in DB
        // update DataGridView and other elements on UI

        // How to return null/void/nothing?
        return ???;
    }
```

Is it illegal/bad practice to await on synchronous methods like `Search()`? I know I can use `Task.Run(Search)` instead but then `Search()` will be executed on another thread (not on UI thread) and I have to use `Invoke()` inside `Search()` very often.

I changed the return value of `Search()` method from 'void' to 'Task' so its awaitable but what do I have to return?

Comment: You don't want to stay on the UI thread if you're doing database operations as it will make the UI hang. Do it the right way on a separate thread. Try to separate out the database code from the code that manipulates the UI into different methods.

Comment: Okay so option 2 should be the better approach because it will not be executed on the UI thread?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it illegal/bad practice to await on synchronous methods like Search()?

Well it's a very bad idea, because your UI will hang, basically.

You should change your `Search` method to `SearchAsync` (for the sake of convention) and use asynchronous database operations to make it properly asynchronous.

Currently, you don't have any true asynchrony: everything will just happen on your UI thread.

Comment: I am using EF5 therefore I can not use async queries? So when/how to receive my data in this case? Is it possible to start an async chain of methods and in the end I do something synchronous?

Comment: @AlmightyMato: You could use `Task.Run` to spin up the database queries in a different thread, and `await` that task in the UI thread.

Comment: I did like you suggest and this works fine. Thank you.